# Number of positive integral solutions for $ab + cd = a + b + c + d $ with $1 \le a \le b \le c \le d$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> How many positive integral solutions exist for: $ab + cd = a + b + c +
>  d $,where $1 \le a \le b \le c \le d$ ?

I need some ideas for how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as
$$(a-1)(b-1)+(c-1)(d-1)=2.$$

Now there are not many possibilities to consider!   If the first product is $0$, the second must be $2$, and if the first product is $1$, so is the second.

If $a=1$, then we need to have $(c-1)(d-1)=2$. Since $1\le c\le d$, this forces $c=2$, $d=3$. And $b$ can be $1$ or $2$, giving the solutions $(1,1,2,3)$ and $(1,2,2,3)$.

If $a>1$, we need $a=2$, else the left hand side is too big. That forces $b=c=d=2$, giving the third solution $(2,2,2,2)$.

**Comment**: Note that in general $ab+pa+qb=(a+q)(b+p) -pq$. This relative of completing the square is occasionally useful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint,I can see only two solution $(1,2,2,3)$ and $(2,2,2,2)$ (till now).However I think there is not any more?!

Comment: Just found and edited almost at the same time you made your comment! Thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks just noticed that too! and when I refreshed you have edited!

Comment: I guess that might be a good gesture for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: start by comparing $ab$ to $a+b$.